# Get parent page html content from facebook iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

Here I am working with facebook application.

I have create page which are working in facebook iframe window.

I want to access main(Parent) window html source from iframe which create by me.

Here I have tried for

**parent.document**  and **window.top.document** and **window.parent**

all three are not working in my case. If you have any other idea then let me know,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access content outside of your IFrame.
Otherwise you could change content outside of it and modify Facebook,
just because your IFrame is loaded inside of Facebook ;)